# I have multiple Google accounts on my phone. How can I delete some of them?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I have an annoying problem with this Samsung Epic 4G touch. I set up a new Gmail account, which I use for Google Talk and the Android Market. However, I logged in to YouTube under two usernames at various points. I am not logged in and when I click Market it defaults to one of the YouTube accounts instead of my Gmail account. Under accounts, it shows all three. How do I delete the two YouTube accounts? I don't want them to access the Market and it does every time even though I no longer log into YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

From the Home screen `Menu | Accounts & sync` should list all of your accounts on the device. Tap the account you want and then tap the "Remove Account" button.